# How can I mount 2.5" SSDs in my Sun Ultra 24's 3.5" drive caddy system?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, adapter

I've just acquired a Sun Ultra 24.  Decent spec for its era, so still some life in it I think.

It has 4 3.5" hard-drive caddys (I believe part number 330-2238 540-3024).  They have plastic rails to screw to a 3.5" drive and a lever mechanism on the front locking them into place; the drives dock against a back panel with SATA plugs protruding from it.

I'd quite like to put a couple of 2.5" SSDs in the box, but it's not obvious how to use them with this caddy system.  I've seen 3.5"/2.5" mount adapters, but I assume they expect cables to run to the drive, and it's not obvious they'd be compatible with the fixed-position SATA back panel the caddys hold the drives against: if the drive's SATA ports didn't end up in exactly the right position they wouldn't work.  If 3.5" SSDs existed, that'd be a simple solution, but they don't seem to be available these days.

Did Sun ever produce a 2.5"-compatible caddy?  Any other solutions to this?  Do drive mount bracket adapters actually work better than I think?

Comment: Maybe you can use duct tape. SSDs weigh virtually nothing and aren't sensitive to vibration.

Comment: @timday - Can you tell me what you did? I'm in the same position... Bought an Ultra 24 for testing open source software with no drives. I did not realize they had a storage plane and cage... Now I am looking to piece something together using two inexpensive SATA drives. The rails/caddies are giving me the problems. *Noloader, gmail* account.

Comment: @jww I have to admit I'm still using 4x3.5" HDDs in the box (using 4 of Sun's hard drive caddys; I'd be surprised it it was possible to avoid the need to use those but you can find them easily enough on ebay).  I did buy a couple of SSD-HDD adapters similar to the ones mentioned in the answer but never got around to using them.

Comment: @jww My Ultra only came with two caddies so I ordered a couple more from someone on ebay; they were described as "SUN Hard Drive Caddy 330-2238 540-3024" and Just Worked.  I put a couple of Hitachi SATA HDDs in them (multiple terrabytes each).  Seemed to slot into place absolutely beautifully. The caddies in the box already had a couple of older smaller Western Digital drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hot swap compatible adapters.

You need something like this: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816132098

Comment: Those look great; found a few more examples varying from some fancy looking and expensive "transposers" to some much cheaper things (which are what I've ordered).

Comment: @Appleoddity - Can you confirm the caddy works with the Ultra 24 storage cage and back plane?

Comment: @jww: Those things aren't caddies for an Ultra.  They're something which turns a 2.5" SSD into the same form-factor as a 3.5" HDD so you can put them in an Ultra's 3.5" drive caddy.  Like I mention in the comment on the question, I did buy a couple of caddys and a couple of these adapters, but in the end just ended up using all 3.5" HDDs.  I think it'd be difficult to put any sort of drive in the Ultra without Ultra caddys.